# In robot framework, How can I get the sum of each value in loop inside the excel?

Tags: loops, sum, robotframework

In robot framework, How can I get the sum of each value in loop inside the excel?
Example:
Cell 4 is 25
Cell 5 is 23
Cell 6 is 21

Sample code of getting values in my loops (not sum yet):

```
${maxRows}  Get Row Count  ${FEEDBACK_TRANSACTION_SHEETNAME}
FOR    ${i1}    IN RANGE    11  ${maxRows}
     ${TOTAL_AMOUNT}  Read Cell Data By Coordinates  ${FEEDBACK_TRANSACTION_SHEETNAME}  4  ${i1}
     Set Suite Variable  ${TOTAL_AMOUNT}
     Exit For Loop If  ${i1} == ${maxRows} 
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there - just sum the current cell with an accumulator variable. Say `${TOTAL_AMOUNT}` will serve that purpose:

```
${maxRows}=  Get Row Count  ${FEEDBACK_TRANSACTION_SHEETNAME}
${TOTAL_AMOUNT}=    Set Variable    ${0}
FOR    ${i1}    IN RANGE    11  ${maxRows}
     ${current value}=  Read Cell Data By Coordinates  ${FEEDBACK_TRANSACTION_SHEETNAME}  4  ${i1}
     ${current value}=  Convert To Integer    ${current value}
     ${TOTAL_AMOUNT}=   Evaluate    ${TOTAL_AMOUNT} + ${current value}
     Exit For Loop If  ${i1} == ${maxRows} - 4
END

Set Suite Variable  ${TOTAL_AMOUNT}
```